# Story of a woman and her mother facing apocalypse together

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, apocalypse

The world is going to end, maybe because of an alien invasion or meteor. Everybody knows that the world is going to end and accepts it because there isn't anything that can be done to avoid it. The Government provides some sedative tablets to the citizens, so that those who don't want to face the doom can go peacefully in their sleep.  A woman along with her mother decide not to take the sedatives. The woman's husband and two children decide the other way.

The story ends with the woman and mother sitting in their front porch and the earth beginning to shake. The woman or her mother says something in the end but the other person was not able to hear it.

I guess the woman was a scientist who had a deep knowledge about what was happening.

I read an online copy of this. Don't remember anything about the date of publishing/author.

Comment: I think I remember this one. It starts out with the female scientist noting that we'd finally made first contact with lots of alien species, including various machine civilisations. She'd found another one that morning who'd basically blown up their own star by adding a foreign element to it. Having identified that the apocalypse was coming (eating the stars?) they make some sort of probe that survived a few seconds longer than the Earth. It was made of an alloy that would resist "the darkness". She and her family end up floating in space for a few seconds before dying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/identify-this-story-about-the-end-of-the-world-possibly-the-big-rip

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure this is "Last Contact" by Stephen Baxter, and a dupe.

Comment: @waldrumpus feel free to add it as an answer here. If the OP indicates it is correct, _then_ we can close as a duplicate. Meanwhile, you can use the reputation that comes with it.

Comment: @starpilotsix - It's really interesting how two people can read the same story but have two *completely different* recollections of what was happening. I barely   remember the subplot with her mother.

Answer (score 5):

This is Stephen Baxter's "[Last Contact](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?403801)" (2007), which I now see has already been identified in the comments.

**The world is going to end, maybe because of an alien invasion or meteor. Everybody knows that the world is going to end and accepts it because there isn't anything that can be done to avoid it.**

The story is told by Maureen, whose daughter Caitlin is one of the astrophysicists who discovered that the [Big Rip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip) is imminent.

> She knew why Caitlin was here, of course. Caitlin had always hinted she would come and deliver the news about the Big Rip in person, one way or the other.
>
> [...]
>
> "Mum, it's October." Caitlin blurted that out. She looked thin, pale, and tense, a real office worker, but then Maureen had always thought that about her daughter, that she worked too hard. Now she was thirty-five, and her moderately pretty face was lined at the eyes and around her mouth, the first wistful signs of age. "October 14th, at about four in the afternoon. I say 'about.' I could give you the time down to the attosecond if you wanted."

People mostly, having nothing else to do, just keep going:

> Maureen said, "I told you people would cope. People do just get on with things."
>
> "We haven't got to the end game yet," Caitlin said. "I went into London the other day. That isn't too friendly, Mum. It's not all like this, you know."

**The Government provides some sedative tablets to the citizens, so that those who don't want to face the doom can go peacefully in their sleep. A woman along with her mother decide not to take the sedatives. The woman's husband and two children decide the other way.**

The implication is that they're actually a euthanasia drug, not merely a sedative, but this otherwise matches the story:

> "We had an early Christmas," Caitlin said. "They'll both miss their birthdays, but we didn't think they should be cheated out of Christmas too. We did it all this morning. Stockings, a tree, the decorations and the lights down from the loft, presents, the lot. And then we had a big lunch. I couldn't find a turkey but I'd been saving a chicken. After lunch the kids went for their nap. **Bill put their pills in their lemonade.**"
>
> Maureen knew she meant the little blue pills the NHS had given out to every household.
>
> "Bill lay down with them. **He said he was going to wait with them until he was sure—you know. That they wouldn't wake up, and be distressed. Then he was going to take his own pill.**"
>
> Maureen took her hand. "You didn't stay with them?"
>
> "**I didn't want to take the pill**." There was some bitterness in her voice. "I always wanted to see it through to the end. I suppose it's the scientist in me. We argued about it. We fought, I suppose. In the end we decided this way was the best."

**The story ends with the woman and mother sitting in their front porch and the earth beginning to shake. The woman or her mother says something in the end but the other person was not able to hear it.**

Other than it being a pergola, not a porch, this is also a match:

> **Caitlin joined her mother in the pergola**, and they sat on the wooden benches, on the thin cushions Maureen had been able to buy. Caitlin shut down her torch to conserve the battery.
>
> [...]
>
> **The ground shuddered**, and there was a sound like a door slamming, deep in the ground. Alarms went off, from cars and houses, distant wails. Maureen hurried back to the pergola. She sat with Caitlin, and they wrapped their arms around each other. Caitlin raised her wrist to peer at her watch, then gave it up. "I don't suppose we need a countdown."
>
> [...]
>
> The ground burst open. The scrap of dewy lawn flung itself into the air, and Maureen was thrown down, her face pressed against the grass. She glimpsed houses and trees and people, all flying in the air, underlit by a furnace-red glow from beneath.
>
> But she was still holding Caitlin. Caitlin's eyes were squeezed tight shut. "Goodbye," Maureen yelled. "They were just saying goodbye." **But she couldn't tell if Caitlin could hear.**

**I guess the woman was a scientist who had a deep knowledge about what was happening.**

Caitlin is an astrophysicist, one of the first people who discovered that the Big Rip was happening:

> "It looks like it. I wanted to see it through," Caitlin said again. "**After all I was in at the start—those supernova studies.**"

**I read an online copy of this. Don't remember anything about the date of publishing/author.**

It was originally published in [*The Solaris Book of New Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?89349), and for a while it was available on the Solaris website. You can still find the story at the [archived version of the website](http://web.archive.org/web/20080725045740/http://www.solarisbooks.com/books/newbookscifi/last-contact.asp).