# Short sci-fi story with matter falling apart, from galaxies to atoms, Earth receives and tries to decipher extraterrestrial transmissions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The plot of this short story revolved in a future around dying universe. Some sort of physical law discovered at that time stated that at some moment forces keeping matter together will vanish, and anything, from galaxies to atoms will fall apart.

People living on Earth started to see how distant objects disappear, at the same time they received a lot of extraterrestrial transmissions that they tried to decipher.

I believe this story was written by an American author.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Could it be "Last Contact" by Stephen Baxter, which was the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/identify-this-story-about-the-end-of-the-world-possibly-the-big-rip)?

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.